# What is the least dense liquid under normal conditions?

Tags: reference-request, density, liquids

What is the least dense liquid under normal conditions, room temperature, one atmosphere of pressure, doesn't combust upon contact with air, also wouldn't kill a human just for being in the same room as it?

Answer (score 18):

[Isopentane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopentane) $\ce{C5H12}$ has the density of $0.6201~\mathrm{g\,cm^{-3}}$ at $20~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ [1, p. 3-330].

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; *CRC Press*, **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.

Comment: That is... surprisingly dense. Water is known to be 'heavy' in common speech, but there aren't really any liquids which are a lot lighter apparently.

Comment: @orlp That's due to the constraint imposed by OP: *the compound must be liquid at NTP conditions*. Once the constraint removed, there are more interesting things such as solution of lithium metal in liquid ammonia or good old [liquid hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen) with the density  of $0.0709~\mathrm{g\,cm^{-3}}$, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @andselisk The famous blue solution is significantly lighter than plain liquid ammonia?

Answer (score 12):

According to

> Hans Jaffe: Eine metallische Verbindung von Lithium mit Ammoniak. Elektrische Leitfähigkeit und galvanomagnetische Effekte. *Z. Physik* 93, 741–761 (**1935**) https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01337859

the saturated solution of lithium in liquid ammonia (approx. $\ce{4NH3 \cdot Li}$) has a boiling point above RT, and is significantly less dense (=0.48 g/ml) than isopentane (0.62), or plain ammonia (0.77):

> ... Mit einer Dichte von 0,48 ist die gesättigte Lösung von Li in
> NH3 die leichteste bei Zimmertemperatur existierende Flüssigkeit. Die
> feste Verbindung ...

I wasn´t able to get the full text, unfortunately. And yes, there is a possibility for it to ignite if not handled under an inert atmosphere. How dangerous I don´t know.

Comment: You could allow non-german speakers who read your answer look for a translation elsewhere (not that the more clever readers wont intuit the meaning), or .... "... With a density of 0.48, the saturated solution of Li in NH3 is the lightest liquid that exists at room temperature."

Comment: @BuckThorn Well, whoever doesn´t get it now finds the translation right underneath. :-)

Comment: What a wonderfully unexpected answer!

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto All thanks to anselisks intriguing comment below!