# What are the least dense fluids?

Tags: density, liquids

[This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114281/what-is-the-least-dense-liquid-under-normal-conditions) question left me wondering what *other* very light (condensed) fluids could exist, at *any* environmental condition.

Obvious candidates for the list are (at their Bp./1 bar)

- LH2 (0.07 g/ml)
- LHe (0.125)
- LNe (nope, 1.21)
- methane (0.42)
- ethane (0.54)
- propane (0.58)

plus those mentioned in the other question

- $\ce{4NH3 \cdot Li}$ (0.48)
- isopentane (lightest "normal" liquid at 25°C, 0.62 g/ml)

To give a definit boundary on possible answers, let´s say the density must be below that of isopentane.

The question is, is there anything else? Perhaps at very *high* temperatures?

(The term "fluids" of course also includes supercritical fluids and gases, those are obviously out. You can always reduce the pressure, and thereby density, on those, until you either have a regular liquid, or you hit the bottom line of your phase diagram at $p=0$. That makes no sense, so I want actual condensed matter.)

Comment: What are LNe, LH2,LNe? Searching on google yields the value of $ \ln e$. Do you mean liquid Ne, $\ce{H2}$, He?

Comment: I believe that's pretty much the size of it. Maybe you want to add liquid diborane (at low T) and liquid Li (at high T), but those won't break the record.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Diborane would be a nice answer, it seems. I found a hardly readable scan of a NASA report that would land it in third place, but can´t get at the references.

Comment: What about the supercritical regime? The question needs to be bounded. Define "fluid".

Comment: @BuckThorn Supercritical makes no sense, obviously. Perhaps I should have said "liquid", but I didn´t want to exclude anything that´s a bit out of the box.

Comment: Well, the boundary between liquid and supercritical fluid is not well defined as far as I am aware, so it would appear to remain a question of semantics :-) In fact, I would be surprised if the theorem of corresponding states didn't have something universal to suggest about this.

Comment: According to Physics Reviews (2013), the lowest density liquid in nature is He-3 adsorbed on alkali metals as a liquid layer (at least in theory) https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.111.045303

Comment: @BuckThorn If you are somewhere within the supercritical regime, you can always reduce the pressure, which will inevitably reduce the density, until you are definitely in the liquid, or the density approaches zero. The former case then is relevant for this question, the latter sort of doesn´t *matter*. Sorry for the pun. ;-)

Comment: Well, these limitations were in original question to make it not overly broad. I think there may be need to make some other besides not gas or supercritical...

Comment: Fluid is anything that flows, i.e. liquids, supercritical fluids, gases and plasma. The least dense fluid, then would be lone atoms (or ions), in intergalactic space.

Comment: Some alkylboranes are light, around ~0.7 . But some are not, closer to 1.4-1.6

Comment: @permeakra Trimethylborane would be a good candidate, en:wp gives it 0.63 at -100°C, and it only boils at -20. The adduct with trimethylamine might be another idea. I was thinking about $\ce{BeH2}$, but wasn´t able to find if it would melt without decomposing at higher pressure.

Comment: @Karl Triethylborane is 0.68 with bp +95 mp -93. Not isopentane, but close enough in my opinion and a nicer liquid phase range

Comment: Okay, I need some clarification on this.
1. Do you mean liquid (like water or oil) or fluid (basically anything that flows, including gas and plasma)?
2. Do you mean density in the term of mass of mole?
Because @DrMoishePippik is correct, if you mean fluid, then intergalactic medium would be the least dense.

Answer (score 3):

The least dense fluid is liquid Hydrogen $\ce{H2}$, at $-255$°C and $1$ bar. Its density is $0.071$  g/mL.

Comment: Actually, [helium-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3#Physical_properties) has a density of $\mathrm{0.059\ g/mL}$ at its normal boiling point of $\mathrm{3.19\ K}$. For comparison, in helium-4 the respective values are  $\mathrm{0.1247\ g/mL}$ at $\mathrm{4.23\ K}$.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto No idea where I got the 0.18 for helium in the question. Tnx!